Align multiple objects to maximise space
Is there an easy way to seperate multiple objects to fill the space without them touching - EG from left to right in the below image.

We have multiple designs that need to go on gang sheets for printing and have objects of all different sizes and would like an easy way to space them to maximise printing space.

You are referring to "nesting".
Illustrator has no such feature or ability.
